# Serializing international characters with jQuery ajax form submit consumed by classic asp

Tags: jquery, serialization, asp-classic

I'm having massive headaches serializing international characters. I'm updating classic ASP pages which have windows-1252 as charset, when I serialize and send via ajax, my german characters are getting corrupted. Has anyone else run into this? any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just in case someone else has this problem, the resolution is to have `<%@ codepage=65001 %>` at the top of the receiving page. jquery.serialize() serializes using utf8 and this basically puts the receiving page in the correct codepage